# Angular ui router mais PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, ui-router

Atualmente eu tenho um array no php que converto para JSON usando o `json_encode` o json e gerado sem problemas.

```
$array = array('a' => 'Olá mundo', 'b' => 'Olá Marte');
$array = json_encode(array);
//$array agora retorna {"a":"Olá mundo","b":"Olá Marte"} .
```

Estou utilizando [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) para trocar de forma dinamica minhas paginas, normalmente quando se deseja enviar parâmetros pelo ui-router usamos

```
<a href="#" ui-sref="ver({parametro:valor})"> clique aqui </a>
```

funciona normalmente, podendo `valor` sem um objeto JSON feito javascript.

Agora quanto eu tento fazer

```
<a href="#" ui-sref="ver({parametro:"<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>"})"> clique aqui </a>
```

O console me retorna o seguinte erro

> ```
> Error: Invalid state ref 'view({video:{'
> D@http://localhost/arte/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:25266
> I/<.link@http://localhost/arte/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:26135
> ab/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:16:69
> ta@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:84:35
> n@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:69:226
> g@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:60:496
> g@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:61:12
> g@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:61:12
> g@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:61:12
> ba/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:60:119
> B/<.compile/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:24965
> ab/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:16:69
> ta@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:84:35
> n@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:69:226
> g@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:60:496
> ba/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:60:119
> gc/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:65:279
> l@http://localhost/arte/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23877
> A/l.compile/</<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:24297
> If/this.$get</m.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:150:426
> w/z.transitionTo/z.transition<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:19286
> h/<@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:134:167
> If/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:148:43
> If/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:145:83
> If/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:148:339
> l@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:101:87
> sg/</t.onload@http://localhost/arte/js/angular/angular.min.js:106:489
>  <a href="#" ui-sref="view({video:{"           titulo":"a","urlvideo":"htt","duracao":"2:2","datapub":"2017-02-15","views":"100","descricao":"white","palavraschave":"ley"}})"="">
> ```

Comment: `Error: Invalid state ref` se nao me engano quando o php hera o json ele coloca aspas duplas `"`, e as aspas do atributo tambem sao duplas, entao acho que quando encontra a primeira aspa do json, meio que fecha a aspa do atributo, e o json fica invalido. so pra ter certeza troca o `ui-sref="ver({parametro:"<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>"})">`por isso `ui-sref='ver({parametro:"<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>"})'>`. Note que attributo `ui-sref`esta com aspas simples `'`

Comment: @NeuberOliveira seguindo seu exemplo precisei apenas tirar as aspas duplas ficando `ui-sref='ver({parametro:<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>})'>` reconheceu o JSON normal, ates por algum motivo o json estava retornando com um `="` no final, mas agora deu certo.

Comment: nao tinha reparado que tinhas aspas em `parametro` ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um grupo de aspas duplas a mais, tente sem elas:

```
<a href="#" ui-sref="ver({parametro:<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>})"> clique aqui </a>
```

Ouse elas forem necessárias, utilize aspas simples:

```
<a href="#" ui-sref="ver({parametro:'<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>'})"> clique aqui </a>
```